# Django Model Filter: need to return the name not the id of a foreign key

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I am trying to filter some data in a Model called WorkPacket

```
work_packets_01012017_25032020 = WorkPacket.objects.all()

work_packets_01012017_25032020 = 
work_packets_01012017_25032020.filter(start_date__gte=datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 
start_date__lte=datetime.date(2020, 03, 25)).values('id', 'number', 'name', 'description', 
'value', 'type', 'status', 'daily_rate', 'creator', 'creation_date', 'closer', 
'closure_date', 'start_date', 'estimated_closure_date', 'estimated_days_overrun', 
'invoice_coding', 'issued_pos', 'purchase_order', 'number_of_days', 
'number_of_billed_days','number_of_remaining_days', 'number_of_over_run_days', 
'effective_daily_rate', 'ahead_behind', 'earnings', 'remaining_earnings', 'reported', 
'projects', 'purchase_order__customer', 'purchase_order__owner')
```

This table has a foreign key "purchase_order" related to another model. At the end of the values returned I am trying to attach the 'purchase_order__customer', 'purchase_order__owner'. This works but is returning the ids of the customer and the owner, not the name. How can I return the names, instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a specific field of the related model returned, you can use the following:

```py
.values(..., 'purchase_order__customer__name', 'purchase_order__owner__name')
```